# delete item by condition in AWS Dynamodb

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

The table in DynamoDB looks as below:

> partition_key, created_at

I intend to delete items based on `created_at` - when the data is too old, then delete it. I tried the following command:

```
aws dynamodb delete-item --table-name my_table --condition-expression "created_at <= 1479655145317"
```

But it complains **aws: error: argument --key is required**, I intend to delete the item not based on partition key, any suggestions? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Partition key is must to delete the item from DynamoDB. There is no workaround to delete the item without providing the partition key.

In the above case, you need two step process.

1) Scan or query (if you have GSI on created_at) to get the partition key that needs to be deleted

2) Use delete item api to delete the item based on partition key

Answer (score 2):

Somewhat related:
Time To Live (TTL) for DynamoDB allows you to define when items in a table expire so that they can be automatically deleted from the database. 
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/TTL.html