# How to delete all items that satisfies certain condition in AWS amplify?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-amplify, aws-appsync

I am developing an web app using AWS amplify.
I want to delete multiple items that satisfies certain condition using a query like the following:

```
mutation delete {
  deletePostTag(condition: {title: {eq: "Hello"}}) {
    id
  }
}
```

However, having tried to run the above query on AWS AppSync console, it complains that `input` field is missing, but unfortunately `input` only accepts `id`.
It seems that the resolver generated by amplify cli does not support deleting multiple items at once.
Do I have to implement a custom resolver?

Answer (score 1):

You can delete multiple items in a batch. Example below and read more [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/appsync/latest/devguide/tutorial-dynamodb-batch.html).

Schema:

```
type Mutation {
    batchDelete(ids: [ID]): [Post]
}
```

Query:

```
mutation delete {
    batchDelete(ids:[1,2]){ id }
}
```

Not 100% sure if conditions are supported here, but hopefully you can test it. If, as I suspect, they are *not* supported then simply issue a query with those same conditions to retrieve matching items and then supply the resulting array of item keys to batchDelete.

Comment: Thank you for answering my question.
I found that according to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43973649/1824552) post, by DynamoDB's nature you need to provide partition key to delete items.
So what I can do is probably first query items that satisfies certain condition, and then use the partition keys of the result to delete items in batch or one by one.